# What is wrong with this piece of code - C++ enumeration?

Tags: c++, enumeration

I'm studying C++ on this website called learncpp.com. I encounter this example they give on enumeration:

```
enum Color
{
 COLOR_BLACK, // assigned 0
 COLOR_RED, // assigned 1
 COLOR_BLUE, // assigned 2
 COLOR_GREEN, // assigned 3
 COLOR_WHITE, // assigned 4
 COLOR_CYAN, // assigned 5
 COLOR_YELLOW, // assigned 6
 COLOR_MAGENTA // assigned 7
};

Color paint(COLOR_WHITE);
std::cout << paint;
```

I copied this example into my editor but the program doesn't compile and gives the following error:

```
error:'cout' in namespace std does not name a type std::cout<<paint;
```

What is wrong with this code and how can I fix it?

Comment: [Works for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6daee018b2b80c5c) - please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Works for me as well.

Comment: Looks like the above duplicate is correct - OP does not have code inside `main()` or other function?

Comment: `#include <iostream>`